# Generating random sublist from ordered list that maintains ordering

Tags: algorithm, sublist

Consider a problem where a random sublist of k items, Y, must be selected from X, a list of n items, where the items in Y must appear in the same order as they do in X. The selected items in Y need not be distinct. One solution is this:

```
for i = 1 to k
    A[i] = floor(rand * n) + 1
    Y[i] = X[A[i]]
sort Y according to the ordering of A
```

However, this has running time O(k log k) due to the sort operation. To remove this it's tempting to

```
high_index = n
for i = 1 to k
    index = floor(rand * high_index) + 1
    Y[k - i + 1] = X[index]
    high_index = index
```

But this gives a clear bias to the returned list due to the uniform index selection. It feels like a O(k) solution is attainable if the indices in the second solution were distributed non-uniformly. Does anyone know if this is the case, and if so what properties the distribution the marginal indices are drawn from has?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why not just traverse the whole original list, deciding on every element, to keep it or not? That would maintain the original ordering and time is linear.

Comment: @noncom that only gives you an average of k items in the list (if you use probability of k/n for selecting the item).  here you need to guarantee k items and have them be random.

Comment: It seems that the first solution allows an item to be selected twice. Is it the case? Or can each item be selected at most once? These are two completely different questions.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear that items may be selected twice. The second algorithm also allows this I believe (I'm using 1-based arrays, although in hindsight I don't know why I did that...).

Comment: I can propose an easy solution with complexity O(n + k) if that will do.

Comment: @izomorphius I was personally interested in an O(k) solution, possibly involving characteristics of the marginal distributions over each of the indices in Y. Others are more than welcome to post other linear solutions though. Perhaps search engine users with similar problems might stumble upon this page who aren't so interested in O(k) specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first index in Y, the distribution of indices in X is given by:

P(x; n, k) = binomial(n - x + k - 2, k - 1) / norm

where binomial denotes calculation of the binomial coefficient, and norm is a normalisation factor, equal to the total number of possible sublist configurations.

norm = binomial(n + k - 1, k)

So for k = 5 and n = 10 we have:

- norm = 2002
- P(x = 0) = 0.357, P(x <= 0) = 0.357
- P(x = 1) = 0.245, P(x <= 1) = 0.604
- P(x = 2) = 0.165, P(x <= 2) = 0.769
- P(x = 3) = 0.105, P(x <= 3) = 0.874
- P(x = 4) = 0.063, P(x <= 4) = 0.937
- ... (we can continue this up to x = 10)

We can sample the X index of the first item in Y from this distribution (call it x1). The distribution of the second index in Y can then be sampled in the same way with P(x; (n - x1), (k - 1)), and so on for all subsequent indices.

My feeling now is that the problem is not solvable in O(k), because in general we are unable to sample from the distribution described in constant time. If k = 2 then we can solve in constant time using the quadratic formula (because the probability function simplifies to 0.5(x^2 + x)) but I can't see a way to extend this to all k (my maths isn't great though).

Answer (score 1):

Unbiased `O(n+k)` solution is trivial, high-level pseudo code.

- create an empty histogram of size n [initialized with all elements as zeros]
- populate it with k uniformly distributed variables at range. (do k times `histogram[inclusiveRand(1,n)]++`)
- iterate the initial list [A], while decreasing elements in the histogram and appending elements to the result list.

**Explanation [edit]:**

- The idea is to chose `k` elements out of `n` at random, with uniform
  distribution for each, and create a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) out of it.
- This histogram now contains for each index `i`, how many times `A[i]` will appear in the resulting `Y` list.
- Now, iterate the list `A` in-order, and for each element `i`, insert `A[i]` into the resulting `Y` list `histogram[i]` times.
- This guarantees you maintain the order because you insert elements in order, and "never go back".
- It also guarantees unbiased solution since for each i,j,K: `P(histogram[i]=K) = P(histogram[j]=K)`, so for each `K`, each element has the same probability to appear in the resulting list `K` times.

I believe it *can* be done in `O(k)` using the order statistics [X<sub>(i)</sub>] but I cannot figure it out though :\

Comment: The term 'order statistics' gives me an interesting direction to look in, so thanks for dropping it in!

Comment: what is a histogram in this context?  do you mean array?  and `histogram[inclusiveRand(1,n)]++]` looks like it has a syntax error?  for a "trivial" solution this is very hard to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure that the order statistics help. They'll give e.g. the probability that the second element of your sublist is X[3], but I don't think you can turn that around to actually generate the sublist.

Comment: @andrewcooke: (1) I was referring to a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). An array is only one way to implement an histogram, I could also use a hash-map. (2) I fail to understand how can a pseudo code have syntax errors, the last `]` refers to closing the explanation **[**k times `histogram[....]++ ** ] **

Comment: @Rawling: I *think* using their distribution function, one can randomly generate X_(i) iteratively. However, as I said - I cannot figure out how it can be done...

Comment: sorry but this still makes no sense to me.  i am not a particularly stupid person - i know what a histogram is, for example - so perhaps you could find some way to make it clearer?  if only so others can understand your genius...

Comment: Do you mean... Generate a value x_(1) of X_(1). Then work out the distribution of X_(2)conditioned on X_(1) = x_(1) and generate a value x_(2). Then work out the distribution of X_(3) conditioned on X_(1) = x_(1) and X_(2) = x_(2) and generate a value...? If so, that sounds like... fun :D

Comment: @andrewcooke: Never meant to claim you are stupid, nor to claim I was a genius, histogram is a technical term, which might not be clear for non-native english speakers. I editted the answer, and added explanation - do you find that clear now? Or is still something missing?

Comment: @Rawling: That was what I thought, but finding the density function and applying it to find a variable at random could be tricky [that's where I got stuck]. If you are planning to attempt it - good luck! and make sure to notify me somehow if you found a solution for it!:)

Comment: I find it hard enough to follow Wikipedia's derivation of the non-conditional density functions. I doubt I'd be able to derive the conditionals myself. Which is depressing as I've only had three years in which to forget my maths degree ¬.¬

Comment: Actually, no conditionals needed. Given the distribution of X_(1) for (k items from 1..n) we can pick Y[1] at random. Then we can calculate the distribution of X_(1) for (k-1 items from Y[1]..n) and pick Y[2]. And so on. However, calculating the distribution of X_(1) is probably itself `O(n)`...

Answer (score 1):

By your first algorithm, it suffices to generate k uniform random samples of [0, 1) in sorted order.

Let X1, ..., Xk be these samples. Given that Xk = x, the conditional distribution of X1, ..., Xk-1 is k - 1 uniform random samples of [0, x) in sorted order, so it suffices to sample Xk and recurse.

What's the probability that Xk < x? Each of k independent samples of [0, 1) must be less than x, so the answer (the cumulative distribution function for Xk) is x^k. To sample according to the cdf, all we have to do is invert it on a uniform random sample of [0, 1): `pow(random(), 1.0 / k)`.

---

Here's an (expected) O(k) algorithm I actually would consider implementing. The idea is to dump the samples into k bins, sort each bin, and concatenate. Here's some untested Python:

```
def samples(n, k):
    bins = [[] for i in range(k)]
    for i in range(k):
        x = randrange(n)
        bins[(x * k) // n].append(x)
    result = []
    for bin in bins:
        bin.sort()
        result.extend(bin)
    return result
```

Why is this efficient in expectation? Let's suppose we use insertion sort on each bin (each bin has expected size O(1)!). On top of operations that are O(k), we're going to pay proportionally to the number of sum of the squares of the bin sizes, which is basically the number of collisions. Since the probability of two samples colliding is at most something like 4/k and we have O(k^2) pairs of samples, the expected number of collisions is O(k).

I suspect rather strongly that the O(k) guarantee can be made with high probability.

Comment: P.S.: if you care about the quality of your samples, please don't do this -- the limitations of floating point will do you in.

Comment: The previous comment refers to the first algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use counting sort to sort Y and thus make the sorting linear with respect to k. However for that you need one additional array of length n. If we assume you have already allocated that, you may execute the code you are asking for arbitrary many times with complexity O(k).

The idea is just as you describe, but I will use one more array cnt of size n that I assume is initialized to 0, and another "stack" st that I assume is empty.

```
for i = 1 to k
    A[i] = floor(rand * n) + 1
    cnt[A[i]]+=1
    if cnt[A[i]] == 1  // Needed to be able to traverse the inserted elements faster
      st.push(A[i])

for elem in st
  for i = 0 to cnt[elem]
    Y.add(X[elem])

for elem in st
  cnt[elem] = 0
```

EDIT: as mentioned by oldboy what I state in the post is not true - I still have to sort st, which might be a bit better then the original proposition but not too much. So This approach will only be good if k is comparable to n and then we just iterate trough cnt linearly and construct Y this way. This way st is not needed:

```
for i = 1 to k
    A[i] = floor(rand * n) + 1
    cnt[A[i]]+=1

for i = 1 to k
  for j = 0 to cnt[i]
    Y.add(X[i])
  cnt[i] =0
```

Comment: This is O(n+k), since at the very least it takes O(n) to initialize the array to 0.

Comment: @DRVic I did say that both in my comment under the OP question and I also mention in this post that if we assume the array has already been allocated and initialized. This is done only once for all similar tasks so depending on the number of execution may be ok to ignore.

Comment: Don't we need to sort `st` so that the second loop generates elements in the right order?

Comment: @DRVic: You can initialize an array in `O(1)`: have a look: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time/

Comment: @oldboy yes that is correct. So what I propose will only be optimizing if n > k*log(k) and it's complexity will be O(n +k) even if the assumptions I mention are true.

Answer (score 0):

The original list X has n items. There are 2**n possible sublists, since every item will *or will not* appear in the resulting sublist: each item adds a bit to the enumeration of the possible sublists. You could view this enumeration of a bitword of n bits.

Since your are only want sublists with k items, you are interested in bitwords with exactly k bits set.

A practical algorithm could pick (or pick not) the first element from X, and then recurse into the rightmost n-1 substring of X, taking into account the accumulated number of chosen items. Since the X list is processed in order, the Y list will also be in order.

Answer (score 0):

The original list X has n items. There are 2**n possible sublists, since every item will or will not appear in a sublist: each item adds a bit to the enumeration of the possible sublists. You could view this enumeration of a bitword of n bits.

Since your are only want sublists with k items, you are interested in bitwords with exactly k bits set. A practical algorithm could pick (or pick not) the first element from X, and then recurse into the rightmost n-1 substring of X, taking into account the accumulated number of chosen items. Since the X list is processed in order, the Y list will also be in order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned pick_k_from_n(char target[], char src[], unsigned k, unsigned n, unsigned done);
unsigned pick_k_from_n(char target[], char src[]
                , unsigned k, unsigned n, unsigned done)
{
unsigned count=0;

if (k>n) return 0;

if (k==0) {
        target[done] = 0;
        puts(target);
        return 1;
        }
if (n > 0) {
        count += pick_k_from_n(target, src+1, k, n-1, done);

        target[done] = *src;
        count += pick_k_from_n(target, src+1, k-1, n-1, done+1);
        }

return count;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char result[20];
char *domain = "OmgWtf!";
unsigned cnt ,len, want;
want = 3;

switch (argc) {
default:
case 3:
        domain = argv[2];
case 2:
        sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &want);
case 1:
        break;
        }
len = strlen(domain);

cnt = pick_k_from_n(result, domain, want, len, 0);

fprintf(stderr, "Count=%u\n", cnt);

return 0;
}
```

Removing the recursion is left as an exercise to the reader.
Some output:

```
plasser@pisbak:~/hiero/src$ ./a.out 3 ABBA
BBA
ABA
ABA
ABB
Count=4
plasser@pisbak:~/hiero/src$
```

Comment: Oops, that should have been appended to the previous reaction. Sorry!

Comment: Note that the selected items in the original problem may be repeated.

Comment: "The selected items in Y need not be distinct." I'll add some output.

Comment: That means they do not have to be distinct. So for input: 123, and k = 2, you may return 11, 12, 13, 22, 23, 33.